# 0 support devices in google play store

Tags: android, google-play, compatibility

When uploading my apk I get 0 supported devices. I use quite a lot of features, and permissions, which it makes it hard to see what is causing it. Hopefully someone can help me.

[playstore screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbUSH.png)

[playstore screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5e4L.png)

update
added androidmanifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="200058"
    android:versionName="2.0.5"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    package="com.flash.smart.alert"
    platformBuildVersionCode="23"
    platformBuildVersionName="6.0-2704002">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.flash.smart.alert.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
    <permission
        android:name="com.flash.smart.alert.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE"/>
    <application
        android:label="@2131034200"
        android:icon="@2130837526"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        supportsRtl="true">
        <activity
            android:theme="@16974121"
            android:label="@2131034199"
            android:name="com.flash.smart.alert.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:configChanges="locale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter
                android:label="@2131034203">
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:scheme="flashsmartalert"/>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.tonikorin.cordova.plugin.autostart.BootCompletedReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.tonikorin.cordova.plugin.autostart.UserPresentReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.tonikorin.cordova.plugin.autostart.PackageReplacedReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.ForegroundService"/>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="com.flash.smart.alert.provider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@2130968577"/>
        </provider>
        <activity
            android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"/>
        <activity
            android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.LoginActivity"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.TriggerReceiver"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClearReceiver"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973909"
            android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClickActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.TriggerReceiver"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.ClearReceiver"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.RestoreReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973909"
            android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.ClickActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushHandlerActivity"
            android:exported="true"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.BackgroundActionButtonHandler"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <category
                    android:name="com.flash.smart.alert"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.GCMIntentService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <activity
            android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.PaintActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.ExpiryInfoActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973840"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@2131230720"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: show the manifest. I think you have declared something incorrectly there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
replace

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>
```

with

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it shows from your library what you have used.May be These are not supporting google play. You can see with changing your library version. Once i had faced this type of problem and i got rid from this by changing a library version.